# iOS Is there a simple setting that makes a view clip rounded corners all the way down the view stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, rounded-corners

I have a view that is applying a corner radius

```
poster.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = theme.cornerRadius
poster.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Non of the subviews are clipped to this area, so if I add a subview in the upper right corner of this view I seem to have to re-apply a rounded corner on that subview.

Any better options?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"Non of the subviews are clipped to this area"* ... add an image or two to show what you're getting, and what you **want** to get.

Comment: Gregory, are you trying to have the subviews be clipped according to the parent's cornerRadius, or are you trying to apply the same corner radius value to all subviews? Please add more context and info, if possible :)

Comment: @MarkosDarkin Exactly your first line, subviews clipped to the parents corner radius without having to set it for each subview.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do for the image to clip it's subviews is just add the subviews and make sure they are overlapping with the clipped corner.

In this example, you can see it works as you intended.

```swift
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    
        imageView.addSubview(exampleView1)
        imageView.addSubview(exampleView2)

        //Setting constraints for top, bottom, leading and half the width of image
        exampleView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        exampleView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        exampleView1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        exampleView1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        exampleView1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        //Setting constraints for top and trailing then giving small width and height
        exampleView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        exampleView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        exampleView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
        exampleView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        exampleView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

If you still see different results it might mean that:

1. Your 'poster' view (parent of the imageView) is changing somehow and resetting the cornerRadius.
2. You are adding subviews to your 'poster' view instead of the imageView itself and, because of it, the cornerRadius will only clip subviews of the imageView, not the shared parent. To fix it, just make sure all subviews have the same parent then add CornerRadius to the parent.
3. Your imageView's contentMode is set to aspectFit and you are mistaking the edges of the rendered image with the edges of the imageView itself and it makes it seem like the cornerRadius is not applied.

Please include more info if none of this works.

Comment: This is indeed correct. It turns out the components were not in the same view heirachy